# Replace groups that have size > 1 with the mean in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

So I want to groupby certain columns and for each group that has size bigger than 1 take the mean in the rest of the columns (if all values are nan then this should be nan if not I want the nans dropped in the mean calculation, which is the default behaviour). Then I want the extra rows dropped. The code below does that:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, np.nan, 100, 63], [2, np.nan, 101, 63], [2, 12, 102, 63],
     [2, 14, 102, 63], [2, 14, 102, 64], [1, np.nan, 200, 63]],
    columns=['group', 'value', 'value2', 'dummy'])
print(df)
df = df.set_index(['group', 'dummy'])
groupby = df.groupby(['group', 'dummy'])
idx = groupby.size() > 1
df_groups_to_process = df.loc[idx]
# the code below would calculate the mean for all groups, huge performance hit
# df.loc[idx, ['value', 'value2']] = \
#     groupby[['value', 'value2']].transform('mean')[idx].values
df.loc[idx, ['value', 'value2']] = \
    df_groups_to_process.groupby(['group', 'dummy'])[
        ['value', 'value2']].transform('mean').values
print(df)
df = df.groupby(['group', 'dummy']).first()
print(df)
```

prints:

```
   group  value  value2  dummy
0      1    NaN     100     63
1      2    NaN     101     63
2      2   12.0     102     63
3      2   14.0     102     63
4      2   14.0     102     64
5      1    NaN     200     63
sys:1: PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance.
             value      value2
group dummy                   
1     63       NaN  150.000000
2     63      13.0  101.666667
      63      13.0  101.666667
      63      13.0  101.666667
      64      14.0  102.000000
1     63       NaN  150.000000
             value      value2
group dummy                   
1     63       NaN  150.000000
2     63      13.0  101.666667
      64      14.0  102.000000

Process finished with exit code 0
```

However, there are a few things that could be improved:

- `df_groups_to_process = df.loc[idx]` not sure if this creates a copy, but since my real data is huge I would like to avoid this altogether and have it incorporated in `df.loc[idx, ['value', 'value2']] = ...` line
- I repeat the groupby operation at the end to call first - how can I avoid this?
- bonus: the `sys:1: PerformanceWarning: indexing past lexsort depth may impact performance.` - not sure what this is about (I actually don't see it on the server). How can I correct it?

Comment: *Then I want the extra rows dropped* what does this mean? what defines an "extra row"

Comment: It's as the output - i mean keep one row per group

Comment: What am I missing here, why can't you just do  `df.groupby(['group', 'dummy']).mean()` and be done?

Comment: I'm with @timgeb on this.

Comment: confirmed: `df.groupby(by=['group', 'dummy']).mean()` produces your desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean of one value is the value itself, so unless I'm missing something there's no need to make a distinction by group size.

Consider

```
>>> df
   group  value  value2  dummy
0      1    NaN     100     63
1      2    NaN     101     63
2      2   12.0     102     63
3      2   14.0     102     63
4      2   14.0     102     64
5      1    NaN     200     63
>>> 
>>> df.groupby(['group', 'dummy']).mean()
             value      value2
group dummy                   
1     63       NaN  150.000000
2     63      13.0  101.666667
      64      14.0  102.000000
```

This looks like your expected output. Please leave a comment if that solves the problem for all input dataframes you might be considering.

Comment: I can't do `df.groupby(by=['group', 'dummy']).mean()` due to performance - the dataframes are huge and mean takes a lot of  time for those size=1 groups

Comment: The groups with size=1 are usually a tiny fraction of several gigabytes dataframes (and a have 100s of tthem)

Comment: Hm, that's an O(1) operation per group. Did you do timings? I doubt that you can cook up anything that's faster, because you'll have to find these groups in any case before you decide to not do anything with them.

Comment: I did timings (as in print out how much time it takes on those huge frames on the server) comparing `df_groups_to_process.groupby(['group', 'dummy'])[
        ['value', 'value2']].transform('mean').values` to `df.groupby(['group', 'dummy'])[
        ['value', 'value2']].transform('mean').values` - is this equivalent to `df.groupby(['group', 'dummy']).mean()` ?

Comment: Will set up some timings and get back to you

Comment: It does seem that your way is faster after all - I ended up with my code through a long and winding road, but I obviously overcomplicated stuff. I would be curious how I could not run the mean calculation at all on the size=1 groups but for now the issue is closed - thanks!!